# docker nginx container doesn't contain nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container

I have a laravel project that runs on a single docker container.
I use docker-composer.yml to configure the container. I use `nginx:latest` base image in my Dockerfile. For some reason when I tried to launch my project with command `docker-compose up` I got this error:

```
web_1  | 2019-05-10 15:51:14,035 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/usr/sbin/nginx'
web_1  | 2019-05-10 15:51:15,037 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/usr/sbin/nginx'
web_1  | 2019-05-10 15:51:17,040 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/usr/sbin/nginx'
web_1  | 2019-05-10 15:51:20,050 INFO spawnerr: can't find command '/usr/sbin/nginx'
web_1  | 2019-05-10 15:51:20,050 INFO gave up: nginx entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
```

I was suprised so I took a look inside the container with `docker exec -ti mycontainername bash` and I couldn't find nginx anywhere. I tried with `nginx -v`, 
`whereis nginx` , `cd /etc/nginx` <-- directory didn't  exist.

So i tried to create a simple container, which containts only nginx.  I should theoretically be able to go to `localhost:80` and see the Nginx welcome message, right?
`docker run --rm -d -p 80:80 --name my-nginx nginx`
well there was no message and when I took a look inside the container
`docker exec my-nginx` I couldn't find nginx anywhere, but if I ran the command `apt-get nginx` it showed that nginx is already the latest version.

FULL DOCKER-COMPOSE.YML

```
version: '1'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      #      dockerfile: web.dockerfile
    working_dir: /var/www/html
#    volumes_from:
#      - app
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
```

full Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-gd
RUN apt-get -y install php7.2-zip

#COPY app /var/www/html/app
#COPY artisan /var/www/html/app/artisan
#COPY bootstrap /var/www/html/bootstrap
#COPY config /var/www/html/config
#COPY database /var/www/html/database
#COPY public /var/www/html/public
#COPY resources /var/www/html/resources
#COPY routes /var/www/html/routes
#COPY storage /var/www/html/storage
#COPY vendor /var/www/html/vendor
#COPY artisan /var/www/html/artisan
#COPY composer.json /var/www/html/composer.json

COPY entrypointcust.sh /entrypointcust.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypointcust.sh

EXPOSE 80

WORKDIR /var/www/html/old

# Add crontab file in the cron directory
ADD cron /etc/cron.d/appcron

# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/appcron

RUN /usr/bin/crontab /etc/cron.d/appcron

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
#RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
#RUN touch /var/www/html/storage/logs/laravel.log

#RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
#RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/storage
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/entrypointcust.sh"]
```

What am I missing?

Comment: upload your complete docker-compose.yml and all the commands you run so far. Also can you run and upload the result of "docker image ls"? My guess is that you have a local nginx image that is built only on your machine.

Comment: Ok, I included Dockerfile as well

Comment: also your  Dockerfile works. I recommend you double check your local images and delete all nginx images. This way your build will download a fresh new one.